# Attachment Not Sending ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, asp.net-mvc-5, email-attachments

So I've been trying to attach/upload multiple files in the website I'm making. The Name, Email, Subject & Message are sending but there's no attachment in the message. The files are getting in the "~/App_Data/uploads" folder, it's there but I don't receive it in e-mail. I can't figure out what's wrong. Please help me. I'm new with this kind of stuff. Thank you! Here's the view code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="contact_form block">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div id="note"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="fields">

                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FromName)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FromName)
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FromEmail)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromEmail, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FromEmail)
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FromSubject)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromSubject, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FromSubject)
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
                    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                        <label for="file1">Attachments</label>
                        <input type="file" name="files" id="file1" multiple/>

                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Message)
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Message, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Message)
                </div>
                 <div class="col-md-12">                 
                     <div>
                         @if ((TempData["recaptcha"]) != null)
                         {
                            <p>@TempData["recaptcha"]</p>   
                         }
                     </div>
                     <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfVHx8TAAAAAMTDxxQrHDCxO1SyXf1GgbgNBZ5a"></div>
                 </div>

                <div class="col-md-12"><input class="shortcode_button" type="submit" value="Send"></div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

And here's the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(EmailFormModel model, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //logic here upload file logic here.
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }
        }

        //Rest of business logic here
        string EncodedResponse = Request.Form["g-Recaptcha-Response"];
        bool IsCaptchaValid = (ReCaptcha.Validate(EncodedResponse) == "True" ? true : false);
        if (IsCaptchaValid)
        {

            var body = "<p>Email From: {0} ({1})</p><p>Subject: {2} </p><p>Message:</p><p>{3}</p>";
            var message = new MailMessage();
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress("***@gmail.com"));  // replace with valid value 
            message.From = new MailAddress("***@ymailcom");  // replace with valid value
            message.Subject = "Your email subject";
            message.Body = string.Format(body, model.FromName, model.FromEmail, model.FromSubject, model.Message);
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
            {
                var credential = new NetworkCredential
                {
                    UserName = "***@gmail.com",  // replace with valid value
                    Password = "***"  // replace with valid value
                };
                smtp.Credentials = credential;
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);
                //return RedirectToAction("Sent");
                ViewBag.Message = "Your message has been sent!";

                //TempData["message"] = "Message sent";
                ModelState.Clear();
                return View("Index");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            TempData["recaptcha"] = "Please verify that you are not a robot!";
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: No where in you code are you adding the attachments to the email. You need to keep track of the paths yo are saving so that you can attach them to the email later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not attaching anything in your code. You need to attach the files to the `MailMessage`.

When you are saving the files keep track of the paths in a list.

```
List<string> paths = new List<string>();
//...other code
foreach (var file in files) {
    //...other code removed for brevity
    //keep file path for attachments
    paths.Add(path);
}
```

When creating your message you can then attach the files

```
//Attach files
foreach (var path in paths) {
    //For file information
    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
    //stream to store attachment
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    //copy file from disk to memory
    using (var stream = fileInfo.OpenRead()) {
        stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
    }
    //reset memory pointer
    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    //get file name for attachment based on path
    string fileName = fileInfo.Name;
    //add attachment to message
    message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(memoryStream, fileName));
}
```

The files are attached based on the paths of where the files were saved to disk. This code can be refactored for better memory management and performance but it's a start. You should be able to handle the rest.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Sir. I'll try to do this, and update you if it works. I hope I can still ask you some questions if something went wrong. Please guide me, I'm really new with this kind of stuff. Thank you your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Somehow there's a error Sir. I think I'm doing it wrong. But I can't figure out what. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are probably missing a curly bracket somewhere. Check the method to make sure you have the method formatted properly

Comment: You're right Sir I'm just missing some curly bracket. Thank you so much for your help Sir. I'll will run it now, I hope I can receive the attachment in my e-mail now. Thank you Sir. I'll update you if it works or. You're a big help.

Comment: Happy it worked for you. Glad to help. If my answer was useful, you can up-vote it. Thanks. Happy coding.

Comment: I'm voting it up Sir but it won't display publicly. :( And I have another question Sir, I hope it's okay. When I'm trying to attach big files the page is just loading. I've been trying to send it for couple of mins now. Then I tried to look at the "~/App_Data/uploads" folders. The files are there but why it is not sending?

Comment: Ok. you don't have enough rep to upvote as yet so don't worry about that. As for your issue, large files may be using up your memory resources. Is it throw any errors? what is the size of the file that is not sending?

Comment: Once I have enough rep I'll upvote it Sir. While I'm typing this it's just sent Sir, it takes like 15mins or more. It consist of 3 files = 1.15MB.

Comment: Think about it like this. first it has to load the file to the server, then save that file to disk. You then load the file from disk into memory and then send it as email attachment. that's at least 4 times the file is passing through memory which may take a while. but at least it works. now you just need to refactor and try to improve memory management.

Comment: Ooooh. So that's how it works. Thank you Sir! But is there a chance that the files will be deleted in the uploads folder once it's already been sent?

Comment: Yes you can delete the file after it has been sent. Using the same list of paths you can loop through them after email is confirmed as sent and create a file Info then call delete on the file. This will remove it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111823/discussion-between-ken-hemmo-and-nkosi).

Answer (score 0):

Replace this part of code and check it works or not

```
      if (fileUploader != null)
                        {
                            HttpPostedFileBase fileUploader;
                            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileUploader.FileName);
                            mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(fileUploader.InputStream, fileName));
                        }
```

Comment: are you  trying to send single attachment for now or multiple ?..if multiple initially try for one attachment

Comment: I'm trying to send a multiple attachments Sir.

Comment: Please try one file for now

Comment: I have a different code for attaching just one file, and it's working properly. I just really don't know why this one's not working.

Comment: Thank you for your help Sir.